# Global Javascript var becomes null

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have an xPages application that use a global variable in javascript. The global variable is a NotesDocument. When the xPage loads, it calls some Java code which populates the global Javascript var.

A bit later I extract some information from that global var and all is well. A bit later in the code I run a function from a Javascript library that tries to access that global var and it's null. I'm not sure why. Nothing else updates that global var.

Can someone point me in a direction to figure this out?

```
    //This is the script library function that throws the null error:
    var revoPayments = 
    {
        //  Calculate if the occupant should see the Revo Pay My Bill Link in the occ navigator
        "renderPayMyBillRevo" : function() 
        {
            var result = false;
            try 
            {
                //  THIS IS WHERE THE GLOBAL VAR IS NULL
                if( parseInt( gUserOccupantProfile.getShowRevoLink() ) == -1 )
                    result = true;
            } catch (e) 
            {
                print(e.message);
            }
            print( "result: " + result );
            return result;
        }
    }
    //This is the calling javascript from the xPage which works fine pulling all the values etc.
    if( gUserOccupantProfile && gUserOccupantProfile !== "null" && gUserOccupantProfile !== "undefined" )
    {
        //  ALL THESE VALUES ARE SET BECAUSE IT'S A VALID OBJECT
        sessionScope.put( "OccupantUNID", gUserOccupantProfile.getDocUNID());
        sessionScope.put( "Tenant_ID", gUserOccupantProfile.gettenant_id() );
        sessionScope.put( "UnitRefNo", gUserOccupantProfile.getUnitRefNo() );
        sessionScope.put( "Resident", gUserOccupantProfile.getResident() );
        sessionScope.put( "FirstName", gUserOccupantProfile.getFirstName() );
        sessionScope.put( "LastName", gUserOccupantProfile.getLastName() );
        sessionScope.put( "CurrentUser", gUserOccupantProfile.getFirstName() + " " + gUserOccupantProfile.getLastName() );
        sessionScope.put( "PropertyAddress", gUserOccupantProfile.getPropertyAddress() );
        var tempStr = gUserOccupantProfile.getcurrent_balance();
        tempStr = tempStr.replace( "$", "" );
        tempStr = tempStr.replace( ",", "" );
        sessionScope.put( "Current_Balance", tempStr );
        sessionScope.put( "PropertyNo", gUserOccupantProfile.getPropertyNo() );
        sessionScope.put( "PropertyName", gUserOccupantProfile.getPropertyName() );
        sessionScope.put( "LastPaymentDate", gUserOccupantProfile.getLast_payment_date() );
        sessionScope.put( "LastPaymentAmount", gUserOccupantProfile.getPayment_amount() );

        gAPropertyProfile = eStarService.getPropertyProfile( sessionScope.get( "PropertyNo" ) );
        //  09.15.2014 - Steven Rieger  :  added code to disable pay my bill for separate properties
        //  Default is to always display the option.
        if( gAPropertyProfile.getDisablePayMyBill().toLowerCase() == "yes" )
            sessionScope.put( "renderPayMyBill", false );
        else
            sessionScope.put( "renderPayMyBill", true );

        sessionScope.put( "renderStatements", myEStatements.renderStatements() );
        print( "Before RenderRevo" );
//  THIS LINE FAILS BECAUSE IN THE SCRIPT LIBRARY CODE ( SEE ABOVE ) THE 
//  GLOBAL VAR IS NULL
        sessionScope.put( "renderPayMyBillRevo", revoPayments.renderPayMyBillRevo() );
        print( "After RenderRevo" );

    //  sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsTitle", "Debug!" );
    //  sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsMessage", "gotLogEntry: " + gotLogEntry );
    //  var dialogOops = getComponent( "dialogOops" );
    //  dialogOops.show();

    }
```

Comment: Quick note: you probably want to change `gUserOccupantProfile !== "null" && gUserOccupantProfile !== "undefined"` to `gUserOccupantProfile !== null && gUserOccupantProfile !== undefined`.

Comment: gUserOccupantProfile is the global defined at the top of my script library ( not shown in the code )

Comment: I read something on line those two would catch issues if they were string values "null" or "undefined" and if( gUserOccupantProfile ) would catch null or undefined objects?

Comment: Only if you compare against the actual `null` and `undefined` values. Comparing against the strings won't help. That would be true if you did this: `gUserOccupantProfile = "null"`, not if you did this: `gUserOccupantProfile = null`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this do to Serialization.  You can't have have global SSJS variable that includes method functions with code. In can include functions with just "static" values I believe.
Suggest you look at this post:  http://www.notesin9.com/2014/05/20/tim-explains-ssjs-object-persistence/
And focus on what Tim Tripcony answered.

I should add that the BEST solution is to move this code to a Java Managed bean.  An alternative SSJS solution might be to instead of putting all those values in different scoped Variables...  create a HashMap and use that to replace all the Scoped Variables.  then that whole map could be passed to a SSJS function in a script library to inspect the map and spit out the answer you're looking for.  Just thinking out loud there...

Comment: I will review that shortly.  I do have to say I have a second javascript function that is very similar but but acts upon a different global SSJS object and that one works fine so I am befuddled.

Comment: I do have a couple of beans ( the two global vars point too ), however, I was trying to keep that logic out of the beans since it is very specific to the UI only and the beans are used all over in different applications.

Comment: Well you can have a "pageBean" to act as a controller for the UI.  I do this all the time with the help of a small framework from Jesse Gallagher - but you could have one manually out there for just a single page.  Though I highly recommend the controller frame work for the UI related code.